Как собрать Linux-систему в ISO-образ?
Я планирую собрать свою сборку Ubuntu, на которой будут все необходимые программы сразу после установки.
Ранее у меня был опыт с такой программой, как Cubic, но она оказалось довольно неудобной из-за отсутствия возможности запускать сервисы.
Я собираюсь сделать chroot или виртуальную машину, где настрою всё как мне нужно, но я не понимаю, как собрать такую систему в iso-образ.
Посоветуйте наиболее простые в понимании способы, как это сделать
